# How to format a usb flash drive to make it accept files larger 4gb?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, ntfs, usb-storage, fat32

What can I do to make a usb flash drive accept files larger 4gb? I noticed that some do not allow storing for single file larger 4gb.

Is it about the format of the pendrive? Instead of FAT32 it should be NTFS?

Any disadvantages when changing the format?

Comment: NTFS is a better format, and will achieve what you need. There are utilities out there that will format fat32 larger than 4gb if you need fat32 for some reason.

Comment: If using Windows, format it as NTFS and if it's for Linux, ext3. Never use FAT variants for USB drives if you can avoid it, as ext2/3/4 are supported across BSD, Linux, and Windows (via Paragon's [LinuxFS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/))

Comment: @jw0914 "Never use FAT variants forcUSB drives"  is bad advice. Unless you are moving files larger then 4 gigs, FAT is the de-facto standard across almost all platforms for USB - including embedded ones. I would also argue one would  better off with NTFS then ext as its easier to support NTFS on Linux then ext on Windows.

Comment: @davidgo You failed to read the whole sentence... How exactly is it difficult to support ext variants on Windows when I linked to the program that allows you to do so? Maybe I'm confused, but you generally have to install packages on Linux for NTFS support, so your statement makes no rational or logical sense. Simply because FAT32 or exFAT is the defacto FS manufacturers default a USB to does not mean either is the best FS... It only means it's convenient for the OEM to do so, not that it's the best FS to use. FAT32 has a 4GB file size limit, whereas exFAT doesn't support ACLs

Comment: @jw0914 I did not fail to read the whole sentence.  I disagree  with your extreme generalisation.  I never implied FAT is the best FS - if there is doubt, I grant you that it is very limited - but argue its "good enough" for many needs - especially those associated with removable disks.  NTFS support for Linux is included in baked in to some distros (this is true for Ubuntu) and easy to get for others from the standard repos.  Its also not subject to the licensing whims of a small company.

Comment: @davidgo You quoted the first part of the sentence, leaving out the last part, which provided context... that's failing to read the entire sentence: _"Never use FAT variants for USB drives **if you can avoid it**"_. How that's bad advice is perplexing, as you've just detailed. Pertaining to LinuxFS, a license isn't needed to read from an ext variant, only to write, format, & auto-mount - considering ext has been around for just shy of thirty years, paying $20 for a lifetime license from the only company that's released Windows software for ext/btrfs/xfs isn't much for the return on investment.

Comment: @jw0914.  My last thoughts on this matter - The OP likely is likely not using Linux (very loosely implied by the question).  If someone is not in the "Linux World" - and I put to you this is likely for the OP - then all the focus on ext filesystems is unwarranted.  It seems its important to you to win this argument, so you can consider yourself the winner. I'm not engaging further on this post.

Comment: @davidgo It had nothing to do with "win[ning] this argument" and everything to do with you taking a two-sentence comment completely out of context.